# Insert sound and image on messagebox in maze

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, audio, messagebox

I am making a scream maze in C# I was wondering how to get a picture and a scream sound file to appear when the cursor enters a label. The label code is this:

```
private void suprise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not much experience in this, but I would start by passing the device number (in case you have multiple devices/sound Cards) into a playSound function.

```
public void playSound(int deviceNumber)
{
    disposeWave();// stop previous sounds before starting
    waveReader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(fileName);
    var waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.WaveOut();
    waveOut.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
    output = waveOut;
    output.Init(waveReader);
    output.Play();}
```

Also look into NAudio for more details.

Comment: How would I insert a photo? Because I want it so when they enter the label, it will display the photo and play the sound.

Comment: can u elaborate about the photo part?

Comment: I actually figured out how to get the photo one there.

Comment: congrats man. way to go. I figured it was a pretty easy concept. but was just trying to make sure I was understanding you correctly.